# Seperate Database for Users

Tags: postgresql, design-patterns, database-design

In my `postgreSQL` I currently have one database with *user* and *business* relevant *tables*. Our company is planing in future to add more categories, therefor I would like to seperate the categories into individual databases, as most of the data is quiet static once initialized. Below I am a showing an example with cars, please keep in mind that our company services differ much more as `Pkw` and `LorryTruck` and need much more extra tables within their scope.

**Current State:**

- PostgreSQL:

  - **CompanyDB**

    - UserTable
    - PkwTable
    - ServiceTable
    - BookingTable

**Future State**

- PostgreSQL:

  - **UserDB**

    - UserTable
  - **PkwDB**

    - PkwTable
    - ServiceTable
    - BookingTable
  - **LorryTruckDB**

    - LorryTruckTable
    - ServiceTable
    - BookingTable

My concern is if and how I could **connect user relevant Data to the desired databases.** In example a user can register for `Pkw` services and might be later on interested in `LorryTruck` services. The main goal is also that a user should only register once on our system.

*Is this possible or could I design this better?*

Please provide your opinion or experiences.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html), not a different database. It's not possible (or easy) to get some data from a different database, while using different schema's is standard and working great.